# Constant app crashes + google play error 960

Tags: nexus-5, crashes

I recently got a new Nexus 5 and I have a lot of issues with the software.

Basically I have 2 major issues which I guess are likely related:

1. Google play store very often gives me an error `Unknown error code during application install: "960"`
2. Many applications often crash with the error message `Unfortunately application <insert-app -here> has stopped working`. I'm under the impression these are mainly stock apps but I'm not 100% sure.

Next I also see some side issues in google chrome, which I suspect have the same reason:

1. Sometimes while browsing the whole phone crashes, I haven't pinned this down to a single action, but it only happens while using chrome, not with any other app or while idling.
2. I often get an error stating "this page cannot be loaded, please reload", after 5-6 times reloading it finally works (or the phone crashes...).

To me it looks like there is some error with a basic android support app (maybe services) that messes everything up but I really can't figure out what it is. I have tried already:

- Factory reset several times, including using recovery mode
- Adding/removing my google account
- Clearing app caches of several apps like google chrome and google play services
- Clearing the cache partition using recovery mode
- Rebooting in safe mode

Comment: As it's new, take it back to the shop and get them to sort it out. This isn't normal behaviour, and it's not on you to fix this.

Comment: I don't know how things are in Belgium, but in the UK if you have to return broken or misdelivered goods, it's up to the seller to pay the delivery costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this page while trying to solve the same problem on my Nexus 5. Here is the succinct answer that worked for me: You need root and to install an app called SD Maid ([Play Store Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm&hl=en)), run it's "CorpseFinder" function, remove the corpses, and reboot. Force closes and 960 errors stopped for me after doing this. I elaborate more [here on this thread](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/826401-google-play-store-error-960-a.html#post6695241) on AndroidForums.com. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the data of every app that fails simply by long pursuing on it and dropping in the app info option that appears on the desktop. This will force the app to «restart» from zero.